# Hanged on "Docker desktop is starting"

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Ive downloaded and installed my docker-desktop gui client for my Windows 10 system. Everything went well during the installation process. But when I clicked on the docker desktop icon the small white whale shown on the notifications tab only reads "Docker Desktop is starting" for hours and hours without any change. Can anyone please provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing the same issue. For me, the solution that works is to kill all of my docker desktop processes from the Task Manager and then click on the desktop client again. Usually, that fixes the problem most of the time. If not I keep trying the same method until it works.